# Collection data for grid ui component in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

Collection data for grid ui component in Magento 2

I want show data by grid but it get all data, how to get it with sku = "VAY", i want show all data have sku = vay

My grid

[image]

My collection

```
class Collection extends 

\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection {

    public function _construct(){
        $this->_init("namespace\module\Model\module","namespace\module\Model\ResourceModel\module");
    }
    protected function _beforeLoad()
    {
        parent::_beforeLoad();
        $this->addFieldToFilter('type',['eq'=>2]);
        return $this;
    }


}
```

di.xml

```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="module_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">namespace\module\Model\ResourceModel\module\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="namespace\module\Model\ResourceModel\module\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">stocklog</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">namespace\module\Model\ResourceModel\module</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter data with ui_component

```
<dataSource name="test" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
        <settings>
            <filterUrlParams>
                <param name="type">2</param>
            </filterUrlParams>
        </settings>
</<dataSource>
```